# Проверка записи на количество символов

Tags: sql, csv

В карточках ЮЛ есть данные по ИНН.
Там могут быть не совпадения по количеству символов, а также вместо цифр могут встречаться другие символы.
Например, верный вариант: 9704175980
Ошибочные: 04175980, 970417598, 9704!75980

Как найти все ошибочные варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у Вас postgresql, то можно так:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE inn !~ '[0-9]{10}'
```

Проверяем содержит ли поле inn 10 цифр подряд и выводим только те строки где условие не соблюдается.

Comment: Спасибо большое!